# Ionic Save large file @Capacitor/filesystem - Out of memory error

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, capacitor, capacitor-plugin

I try to store multiple files in the file storage by using the @Capacitor/filesystem Plugin.

On large files I'm facing the following error - testet on my One Plus Pro 8 (Android 12):

```
W/System.err: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 150994952 byte allocation with 25165824 free bytes and 140MB until OOM, target footprint 280973616, growth limit 402653184
```

**Code for saving the files:**

```
Filesystem.writeFile({
        path,
        data: file.base64,
        directory: Directory.Data,
        recursive: true
      })
```

**Project configuration:**

```
**Ionic**:

   Ionic CLI                     : 6.19.0 (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@ionic/cli)
   Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 6.0.8
   @angular-devkit/build-angular : 13.0.4
   @angular-devkit/schematics    : 13.0.4
   @angular/cli                  : 13.0.4
   @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 5.0.3

**Capacitor**:

   Capacitor CLI      : 3.4.1
   @capacitor/android : 3.4.1
   @capacitor/core    : 3.4.1
   @capacitor/ios     : not installed

**Utility**:

   cordova-res : not installed globally
   native-run  : 1.5.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the following package wich solved my problem:

[Capacitor-blob-writer](https://github.com/diachedelic/capacitor-blob-writer)

It splits the file into multiple parts if it's to low.

Answer (score 0):

Saving large files is currently not supported (see https://github.com/ionic-team/capacitor/issues/984).

The Capacitor team has communicated on Discord that there are plans to add support with Capacitor 4.

Comment: The last comment in your posted issue refers only to files safed as Blobs. I convert all my files to a base64 string. So that shouldn't be the problem!

Comment: You can't transmit infinitely large strings. At some point, as in your case, there will be an OOM. Then the data must be transferred optimized (in smaller parts). However, such an interface does not yet exist.